# Android import a project with c++ code,error: source file is not valid UTF-8

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I imported the bitcoin wallet project, it builds success, but when run it, I got this error:

> b#e]
>   error: source file is not valid UTF-8

Anyone knows? Thank you!

Comment: probably your source files include some non-UTF8 encoding characters.

Comment: yes,but  I delete it and recreate it,did not work,   the project  url :https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/tree/master/wallet/cpp

Comment: I just clone the project and it compiles flawlessly on my macOS.

Comment: Have you tried using a text editor like Notepad++ which can handle this type of conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I just clone the project and it compiles/runs flawlessly on my macOS.

Do check below encoding is **LF-UTF-8** selected for **all your files**.

[image]

Comment: wow,thank you,  my code is UTF-8  but not  LF  runtime  UTF-8

Comment: Good, glad to see it helped.